# Receive email message when user submits contact form using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-blade

I currently have a Laravel application that has a contact form. When the form is submitted, the users name, email, phone number and message all properly get stored in my DB, the user receives a confirmation email and I don't receive any errors. My question is, as the person who owns the form, how do I use Laravel to receive the users name and message to my gmail account? I am using gmail smtp to send emails to the user who submits the form. I want the users contact form information (just name and message) to be sent to my gmail email.

MessagesController.php

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Mail\MessageCreated;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'phonenumber' => 'required|min:11',
            'message' => 'required|min:5',
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect(url()->previous() . '#contact')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        $message = Message::create($request->all());

        Mail::to($message->email)->queue(
            new MessageCreated($message)
        );


        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your message has been 
            successfully sent. We will reach out to you soon');
    }
}
```

Model: Message.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function email(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Message::class);
    }
}
```

Mailable: MessageCreated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MessageCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.message-created');
    }
}
```

Message the user receives: message-created.blade.php

```
    @component('mail::message')

We appreciate you taking the time to contact us. We will be reaching out to you soon.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'mysamplesite.io'])
Back to homepage
@endcomponent

Thank you,<br>

@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel makes it super easy.

In your controller after `Mail::to() ...`, simply add the following piece of script:

```
Mail::raw("name: $message->name \n message: $message->message", function($message) {
      $message->to('your-gmail-address')
      ->subject('New contact form is submitted.');
 });
```

Comment: Happy that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You put your email in queue so you should ru `php artisan queue:work` to send it or use `send` function instead of `queue`